# Excel - changing table layout

Tags: excel

I want to have below conversion:

[image]

How to achieve? Thanks.

Comment: a) I get that Excel is not your primary field of knowledge but we generally like to see **some** level of original effort. b) Are those ListObject table or just daya typed into a worksheet? c) [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formulas for retrieving multiple matches generally rely to some extent on the row number. In the case of a ListObject table, the row from the [.DataBodyRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.listobject.databodyrange.aspx) must be adjusted byt the row of the [.HeaderRowRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.listobject.headerrowrange.aspx).

In Table3 across the first row in the DataBodyRange,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table2, AGGREGATE(15, 6, (ROW(Table2)-ROW(Table2[#Headers]))/
                  (Table2[class]=Table3[[#Headers],[a]]), ROW(1:1)), 2), TEXT(,))
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table2, AGGREGATE(15, 6, (ROW(Table2)-ROW(Table2[#Headers]))/
                  (Table2[class]=Table3[[#Headers],[b]]), ROW(1:1)), 2), TEXT(,))
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table2, AGGREGATE(15, 6, (ROW(Table2)-ROW(Table2[#Headers]))/
                  (Table2[class]=Table3[[#Headers],[c]]), ROW(1:1)), 2), TEXT(,))
```

The formulas should autofill into the remaining [ListObject object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174247.aspx) cells. Be sure to expand the table vertically to catch all potential matches.

[image: transpose_tables_listobjects]

I'm not quite sure why Tom was not listed in your samepl as being from class C so I;ve assumed it was a typo.